# Access/Set an Observer Property With a Dot in the Name in JSViews

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsviews

I believe the title & my simplified [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bassmanpaul/DcAmj/7/) explains my predicament.

Basically I am dealing with an extremely large & multidimensional observer object containing folders & files, all of which have dynamic property names.

When it comes to using the Observer `setProperty()` function, I am struggling to find a way to use this on properties with a dot in the name such as "**file.png**". This is obviously because when the full stop appears in the set property path JSViews believes it to be a step deeper in the object tree.

Aka:

`path.fileWithoutExt.attrs` = Works.

`path.fileWithExt.png.attrs` = Fails.

So my question is "**Is there a way to achieve property setting, or is it not possible or a feature request?**" Could it be something like:

```
root.path.[file.dot].more
```

or:

```
root.path.{{file.dot}}.more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass in paths like `"object['keyName'].foo"` as first parameter of `setProperty`. (That parameter does expect simply dot-separated paths).

But you don't need to. Just pass the actual object to `$.views.observable(...)` then you only need to pass the leaf property name to `setProperty`:

```
$.observable( files.images[n] ).setProperty( 'modified', 'Modified!' );
$.observable( files.images[n] ).setProperty( 'alias', a );
```

[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DcAmj/9/): all three work...

Answer (score 0):

`path["fileWithExt.png"].attrs` = Works.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried your suggestion but it doesn't seem to work: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bassmanpaul/DcAmj/8/)? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Paul I've never heard of JsViews before. I just checked it out. Turns out the `setProperty` method doesn't support passing in strings in that format. You can do `object['keyName']` in JavaScript, but passing a string as in `"object['keyName']"` into a method/function doesn't automatically mean it will work like real JavaScript because it's not a JavaScript expression, it's just a string. That being said , you can either replace the periods with underscores as in `"fileName_png"`, or file a bug report with JsViews so they can add support for that format of string input to `setProperty`.

Comment: I contemplated doing a string replace before & after but the data set is huge so would be a massive performance hit, I was hoping there would be a workaround but I guess I'll file a feature request/bug. Thanks anyway!