# Set an Observer Key in JSViews

Tags: jsviews

Basically can an observer object's key be rename in JSViews?

This is related to [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23608289/access-set-an-observer-property-with-a-dot-in-the-name-in-jsviews) and my updated [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/bassmanpaul/DcAmj/12/), 
in which I rename files where the file name is the object property as well as the key.

My real world example is actually using an `onBeforeChange` helper to perform the rename which is provided the arguments: `oldValue` & `value`. 
Then I use the **oldValue** to navigate through the observer object to rename. **But**, because I don't rename the object key as well further renames will fail because the **oldValue** is now out of sync.

I hope that explanation plus the above fiddle makes sense... :s

Thanks for you consideration!

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you are asking - what you mean by "can an observer object's key be renamed?".

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear. So if I have `obj = { key : 'value' }` the following is possible: `$.observable( obj ).setProperty( 'key', 'value' )` leaving: `obj = { key : 'value1' }`. But I was wondering if there is a way of achieving a key rename like: `$.observable( obj ).setProperty( 'key', 'key1' )` leaving: `obj = { key1 : 'value' }`. Is that example a bit clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve something close to that by calling:

```
$.observable(object).setProperty("newKey", object.key);
$.observable(object).setProperty("key", undefined);
```

That will leave a property object.key with the value undefined, but will not actually remove the property.

If you want you can then call

```
delete object.key;
```

There will probably be a new `$(object).removeProperty("someKey")` in an upcoming update - which will allow you to write:

```
$.observable(object).setProperty("newKey", object.key);
$.observable(object).removeProperty("key");
```

---

#### UPDATE

You can now use [removeProperty](https://www.jsviews.com/#removeprop):

```
$.observable(object).removeProperty("key");
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That proposal would work really well in theory but reference to the original object item would be lost. 
I tried (unsuccessfully) to apply your logic to my original Fiddles to give an idea of where I'm coming from: 

[Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/bassmanpaul/DcAmj/13/), 
[Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/bassmanpaul/DcAmj/14/). 
1: Creates new objects but changes aren't reflected in the DOM. 
2: Creates new objects & new item is added in the DOM. 

Unless there is a way to copy the event/observer reference across to preserve the link? (Let me know if that was unclear!).

Comment: P.S. I'm looking forward to the `removeProperty()` feature & will make do with the `delete` for now!

Comment: FYI `removeProperty()` is available, since commit 54 - July 11th